# 3 dots ellipsize are not always shown

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView in my layout which has 2 lines and in case the text in it is too long, it should be cut with 3 dots.
The problem is that the 3 dots are not always shown. Sometimes if the text has '\n' in the middle or too many spaces, the 3 dots are not shown and the user can't know that the text is not full.

If you find anything wrong with my xml, please tell me.
Thanks

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/messageText"
    style="@style/bubblesTextStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/toString"
    android:layout_below="@id/inbox_contactName"
    android:layout_marginTop="-2dp" />

<style name="bubblesTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Theme">
    <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">2</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#666666</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: could be related to this bug
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13895  ?

Comment: I don't think it's the same bug, I use 2 lines and not a single line.

Comment: are you using right to left characters?  I think the bug is most appicable to mutli-line, the fix dealt with changing to single line.  Also it appears if you switch your locale to Hebrew or Arabic it might also help

Comment: No, the texts are in English. Thanks

Comment: @Yaniv : did you find a solution for this or not yet ?

Comment: It is not relevant anymore. But the solution I've used was not with XML.

Comment: @Yaniv You should post your solution, because I have the same issue and I wonder how to fix it.